# Bounty Questions: Does bounty still get awarded if user is near or over daily rep limit?

Tags: discussion

On questions that contain a bounty on them, if the originator of the bounty awards it to a user that is either near or at their daily rep limit (200 rep points), does bounty get negated? Or does the rep award by bounty not count against daily limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As a special bonus, any reputation you earn from being awarded a bounty is exempt from the daily reputation cap.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty